# Django REST POST and GET different throttle scopes

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have django-rest view class `Photo` with get and post methods and I want to allow users to make one POST photo upload an hour and 1000 GET photo requests in minute. By default I can set `throttle_scope` for all `APIView` (both get and post).

How to perform it? Create two different views with different scopes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

it's a little bit tricky, and I didn't test it.

override the `get_throttles` method in your APIView.

```
class PhotoView(APIView):
    throttle_scope = 'default_scope'

    def get_throttles(self):
        if self.request.method.lower() == 'get':
            self.throttle_scope = 'get_scope'
        elif self.request.method.lower() == 'post':
            self.throttle_scope = 'post_scope'

        return super(PhotoView, self).get_throttles()
```

#### solution 2

You should define your own `ScopedRateThrottle` class for different `scope_attr`.

```
class FooScopedRateThrottle(ScopedRateThrottle):
    scope_attr = 'foo_throttle_scope'

class BarScopedRateThrottle(ScopedRateThrottle):
    scope_attr = 'bar_throttle_scope'

class PhotoView(APIView):
    foo_throttle_scope = 'scope_get'
    bar_throttle_scope = 'scope_post'

    def get_throttles(self):
        ret = []
        if self.request.method.lower() == 'get':
            return [FooScopedRateThrottle(), ]
        elif self.request.method.lower() == 'post':
            return [BarScopedRateThrottle(), ]
        else:
            return super(PhotoView, self).get_throttles()
```

FYI. related source code:  [get_throttles](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L272) and [ScopedRateThrottle](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L207)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like to this trigger a throttle based on HTTP method

```py
#settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'get': '2/sec',
        'options': '2/sec',
        'head': '2/sec',
        
        'post': '1/sec',
        'put': '1/sec',
        'patch': '1/sec',
        'delete': '1/sec',
    }
    ...

}
```

```py
#viewset
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_throttles(self):
        self.throttle_scope = self.request.method.lower()
        return super().get_throttles()
    ...
```